# Is it possible to filter horizontally?

Tags: excel, vba, function, formula

Formula `=LET(_x,XLOOKUP(G18,B1:P1,B2:P16),FILTER(HSTACK(A2:A16,_x),_x<>0))` works well with vertical filtering, is it possible to filter horizontally as highlighted in green color in the snapshot?

[image: ![enter image description here]
Need like this:
[image]

Comment: Use `INDEX()/MATCH()` instead.

Comment: Transpose twice; =transpose(LET(_x,XLOOKUP(G18,B1:P1,transpose(B2:P16)),FILTER(HSTACK(A2:A16,_x),_x<>0)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try `INDEX()` with `MATCH()` or `XMATCH()` function.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$I$14,XMATCH($A18,$A$2:$A$14),XMATCH($C$17,$B$1:$I$1))
```

[image]

Comment: @MadhuPrakash Your expected result just showing results which is possible by vertical filer like `=FILTER(B2:I14,A2:A14=A18)`.

Comment: Are you looking for `=FILTER(VSTACK(B1:I1,FILTER(B2:I14,A2:A14=A18)),FILTER(B2:I14,A2:A14=A18)>0)` as per my screenshot?

Comment: Check this out.
https://excelchamps.com/formulas/horizontal-filter/

Also.
https://exceljet.net/formulas/filter-horizontal-data

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B20`

```
=LET(x,FILTER(B2:P16,A20=A2:A16),
VSTACK(FILTER(B1:P1,x<>0),FILTER(x,x<>0)))
```

---

As suggested by **[P.b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12634230/p-b)**, using `Structured References` and adding `y` for `x<>0`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B20`

```
=LET(x,FILTER(B2:P16,A20=A2:A16),
y,x<>0,VSTACK(FILTER(B1:P1,y),FILTER(x,y)))
```

---

```
=LET(x,FILTER(Table1,A20=Table1[Description]), 
y,x<>0, VSTACK(FILTER(Table1[#Headers],y),FILTER(x,y)))
```

---

Comment: very nice. Maybe add a `y` in there, to calculate the `x<>0` once only: also added table references, since in the previous question/comments I noticed his table was named `Table1`:
`=LET(x,FILTER(Table1,A20=Table1[Description]),
y,x<>0,
VSTACK(FILTER(Table1[#Headers],y),FILTER(x,y)))
`